# Rails 7 import custom JS file net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, import-maps

I am using Rails 7 with importmap and esbuild. The assets:precompile task succeed but when I open the webpage I see this in JS console

> GET https://staging.example.com/assets/src/jquery net::ERR_ABORTED 404
> GET https://staging.example.com/assets/utility/direct_upload
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 GET
> https://staging.example.com/assets/utility/manual_keywords
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 GET https://staging.example.com/assets/src/toastr
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 GET
> https://staging.example.com/assets/utility/modals net::ERR_ABORTED 404
> GET https://staging.example.com/assets/controllers net::ERR_ABORTED
> 404 GET https://staging.example.com/assets/custom/init
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 GET
> https://staging.example.com/assets/custom/dropdown net::ERR_ABORTED
> 404 https://staging.example.com/assets/custom/notification
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404

**app/assets/config/manifest.js**

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_tree ../builds
```

app/assets/javascript/application.js

```
require('@rails/ujs').start();
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
ActiveStorage.start()
import "./src/jquery"
import Popper from "popper.js"
import 'bootstrap'
import dataTable from 'datatables.net-bs4'
dataTable(window, $)
import "chartkick"
import "chart.js"
import "./src/toastr"

import './utility/direct_upload'
import 'utility/manual_keywords'
import './utility/modals'
import "./controllers"
import './custom/init'
import './custom/dropdown'
import './custom/notification'
```

**config/importmap.rb**

```
pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@hotwired/turbo-rails@7.1.3/app/javascript/turbo/index.js"
pin "@hotwired/turbo", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@hotwired/turbo@7.1.0/dist/turbo.es2017-esm.js"
pin "@rails/actioncable/src", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@rails/actioncable@7.0.3/src/index.js"
pin "@rails/activestorage", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@rails/activestorage@6.0.5/app/assets/javascripts/activestorage.js"
pin "popper.js", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.js"
pin "bootstrap", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
pin "jquery", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.js"
pin "datatables.net-bs4", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:datatables.net-bs4@1.12.1/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"
pin "datatables.net", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:datatables.net@1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"
pin "chartkick", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:chartkick@4.2.0/dist/chartkick.js"
pin "toastr", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:toastr@2.1.4/toastr.js"
pin "chart.js", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:chart.js@3.8.0/dist/chart.esm.js"
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "node esbuild.config.js",
    "build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules"
  }
```

**esbuild.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')
const rails = require('esbuild-rails')

require("esbuild").build({
  entryPoints: ["application.js"],
  bundle: true,
  outdir: path.join(process.cwd(), "app/assets/builds"),
  absWorkingDir: path.join(process.cwd(), "app/assets/javascript"),
  watch: process.argv.includes("--watch"),
  //inject: ["inject-jquery.js"],
  plugins: [rails()]
}).catch(() => process.exit(1))
```

**layout.html**

```
    <%#javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload"%>
<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
```